# Where can I find my backend files on wix site?

Tags: velo

I want to access php files, but I don't know their url. Wix support says files are located in "src/backend". So I entered "wix.com/src/backend/send.php", but I failed - 404 eror. Where are files on wix server?

Answer (score 3):

"Server files" (a.k.a "Web Modules") are not any server files or Wix internal server files.

Web Modules are files created by you <sup>[1]</sup> using the Wix editor. They only can be JavaScript files and can consumed only by the site's client files (or as [http-functions](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/wix-http-functions)).

For more information

- https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-working-with-the-velo-sidebar#backend
- https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-web-modules-calling-backend-code-from-the-frontend

---

[1]

[image: screenshot of creating a web module file]